# After timeout of session, page not completely cleared

Tags: c#, asp.net

We have an issue, when the session timeout occurs - it logsoff the user and then presents the login screen. The issue is we have a page header which has tabs for user to hit. But we also present most common tab grid automatically. The page header stays. So after the timeout, that page header is there and new page header displays so there are 2 of them.
way out is to x out and relogin. But there must be some way to clear the entire page when there is timeout, this is my header page

<

```
%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Interchange.aspx.cs" Inherits="FDB.Views.Interchange" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script lang="jv" type="text/javascript">

        function SetHiddenValue(fieldName, val) {
            if (hfCommon.Contains(fieldName))
                hfCommon.Set(fieldName, val);
            else
                hfCommon.Add(fieldName, val);
        }

        function GetHiddenValue(fieldName) {
            if (hfCommon.Contains(fieldName))
                return hfCommon.Get(fieldName);
            else
                return null;
        }

        function ImageClick(s, e) {
            var val = GetHiddenValue('ShowHideFilter');
            if (val == null)
                SetHiddenValue('ShowHideFilter', true);
            else {
                SetHiddenValue('ShowHideFilter', !val);
            }
            val = GetHiddenValue('ShowHideFilter')
            gvPBMCharges.PerformCallback('ShowHideFilter,' + val.toString());
        }

        function TreeCheckedChanged(s, e) {
            gvPBMCharges.PerformCallback(e.node.name + '');
        }

        function ColExpClickFacility() {
            //debugger;
            var divM = document.getElementById('ASPxRoundPanel1_div3');
            if (divM != undefined && divM != null) {
                if (divM.style.display == 'block') {
                    divM.style.display = 'none';
                    hlColExpFacility.SetText('Expand Facility');
                }
                else {
                    divM.style.display = 'block';
                    hlColExpFacility.SetText('Collapse Facility');
                }
            }
        }

        function ColExpClick() {
            var divM = document.getElementById('div1');
            var divTop = document.getElementById('divTop');
            if (divM != undefined && divM != null) {
                if (divM.style.display == 'block') {
                    divM.style.display = 'none';
                    //s.SetImageUrl('../Content/Images/expand.png');
                    hlColExp.SetText('Expand Instructions');
                    divTop.style.height = '45px';
                }
                else {
                    divM.style.display = 'block';
                    //s.SetImageUrl('../Content/Images/collapse.png');
                    hlColExp.SetText('Collapse Instructions');
                    divTop.style.height = '165px';
                }
            }
        }

        function CheckedChangedSelectAll(s, e) {
            if (s.GetChecked()) {
                cblFacility.SelectAll();
            }
            else {
                cblFacility.UnselectAll();
            }
            gvPBMCharges.PerformCallback('');
        }

        function SelectedIndexChangedFacility(s, e) {
            gvPBMCharges.PerformCallback('');
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <div runat="server" id="divTop">
                <div runat="server" id="divTitle" style="float: left; width: 50%;">
                </div>
                <div runat="server" id="divFilter" style="float: right; text-align: right; width: 49.84%; height: 34px; padding-top: 10px;">
                    <table border="0" style="width: 100%;">
                        <tr>
                            <td style="padding-left: 3px; padding-top: 3px; text-align: right;">
                                <div runat="server" id="div2" style="width: 100%; padding-bottom: 5px;">
                                    <dx:ASPxHyperLink runat="server" ID="hlColExp" Font-Underline="true" ClientInstanceName="hlColExp" Text="Expand Instructions" NavigateUrl="javascript:ColExpClick();">
                                    </dx:ASPxHyperLink>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td style="padding-left: 3px; text-align: right; width: 90px;">Select Patient:
                            </td>
                            <td style="padding-left: 3px; text-align: right; width: 215px;">
                                <dx:ASPxComboBox runat="server" ID="cboPatient" ValueField="Id" TextField="Name" NullText="Select patient from drop down" Width="200">
                                    <ClientSideEvents SelectedIndexChanged="function(s,e){ gvPBMCharges.PerformCallback(''); }" />
                                </dx:ASPxComboBox>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
```

Comment: You have provided no code related to logging out. Did you forget to include some code?

Comment: The code for the header and tab grid would be good as well. Can't understand anything with just this

Comment: sorry let me reset this.